# Unable to see images by facets in liferay search

Tags: search, liferay

We are following this link [Faceted search](https://dev.liferay.com/discover/portal/-/knowledge_base/6-2/searching-for-content-in-liferay) to configure search portlet for users to search only for images in Liferay.We are able to see only images but the facets are not showing up to navigate by image file extensions.We are using Liferay 6.2 ce-ga3[image: Missing image extension facets]

Cross posted on https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/view_message/91545697
as there were no answers on the forum.
Edit:Facets that were updated in search portlet
`{
    "displayStyle": "asset_entries",
    "static": true,
    "weight": 1.5,
    "order": "OrderHitsDesc",
    "data": {
    "values": [
        "com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.model.DLFileEntry"
    ],
    "frequencyThreshold": 0
    },
    "className": "com.liferay.portal.kernel.search.facet.AssetEntriesFacet",
    "label": "asset-type",
    "fieldName": "entryClassName"
},
{
    "displayStyle": "asset_entries",
    "static": true,
    "weight": 1.5,
    "order": "OrderHitsDesc",
    "data": {
    "values": ["bmp", "gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "odg", "png", "svg"],
    "frequencyThreshold": 0
    },
    "className": "com.liferay.portal.kernel.search.facet.MultiValueFacet",
    "label": "images",
    "fieldName": "extension"
}`

Comment: I am not aware that file name extensions are available as facets. Did you create that facet yourself?

Comment: No,I referred to the above referred link to configure facets for searching only images.So the search limits itself to searching only docs and media assets only.If I understand correctly,the facets should reflect navigating by image types.